# Test Groovy class that uses System.console()

Tags: groovy, spock

I have a groovy script that asks some questions from the user via a java.io.console object using the readline method.  In addition, I use it to ask for a password (for setting up HTTPS).  How might I use Spock to Unit Test this code?  Currently it complains that the object is a Java final object and can not be tested.  Obviously, I'm not the first one trying this, so thought I would ask.

A sketch of the code would look something like:

```
class MyClass {

   def cons

   MyClass() {
     cons = System.console()
   }

   def getInput = { prompt, defValue ->
     def input = (cons.readLine(prompt).trim()?:defValue)?.toString()
     def inputTest = input?.toLowerCase()
     input
   }
}
```

I would like Unit Tests to test that some mock response can be returned and that the default value can be returned.  Note: this is simplified so I can figure out how to do the Unit Tests, there is more code in the getInput method that needs to be tested too, but once I clear this hurdle that should be no problem.

**EDITED PER ANSWER BY akhikhl**
Following the suggestion, I made a simple interface:

```
interface TestConsole {
    String readLine(String fmt, Object ... args)
    String readLine()
    char[] readPassword(String fmt, Object ... args)
    char[] readPassword()
}
```

Then I tried a test like this:

```
def "Verify get input method mocking works"() {

    def consoleMock = GroovyMock(TestConsole)
    1 * consoleMock.readLine(_) >> 'validResponse'

    inputMethods = new MyClass()
    inputMethods.cons = consoleMock

    when:
    def testResult = inputMethods.getInput('testPrompt', 'testDefaultValue')
    then:
    testResult == 'validResponse'
}
```

I opted to not alter the constructor as I don't like having to alter my actual code just to test it.  Fortunately, Groovy let me define the console with just a 'def' so what I did worked fine.

The problem is that the above does not work!!!  I can't resist - this is NOT LOGICAL!  Spock gets 'Lost' in GroovyMockMetaClass somewhere.  If I change one line in the code and one line in the test it works.

Code change:

```
From:
    def input = (cons.readLine(prompt).trim()?:defValue)?.toString()
To: (add the null param)
    def input = (cons.readLine(prompt, null).trim()?:defValue)?.toString()
```

Test change:

```
From:
    1 * consoleMock.readLine(_) >> 'validResponse'
To: (again, add a null param)
    1 * consoleMock.readLine(_, null) >> 'validResponse'
```

Then the test finally works.  Is this a bug in Spock or am I just out in left field?  I don't mind needing to do whatever might be required in the test harness, but having to modify the code to make this work is really, really bad.

Comment: FYI: forgot to mention, I am using Spock-0.7-groovy-2.0.jar

Comment: You assert that "having to modify the code to make this [test] work is really, really bad.". That depends. Doing TDD/BDD well often requires the code to be well designed and modular to be effectively testable, especially if you want to test with mocks and stubs. So if a test framework pushes you to make your code more modular or configurable then it might be considered "really, really good". Requiring collaborators to be passed as constructor args instead of hard coded might fit in that category. Check out the excellent GOOS book - Growing Object-Oriented Software Through Tests.

Comment: No problem with your statement, my assertion was (way) too strong.  Nonetheless, in this instance, I still feel that needing to change the code solely to help the testing framework discern the proper mocked method is not okay...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right: since Console class is final, it could not be extended. So, the solution should go in another direction:

1. Create new class MockConsole, not inherited from Console, but having the same methods.
2. Change the constructor of MyClass this way:

   MyClass(cons = null) {
     this.cons = cons ?: System.console()
   }
3. Instantiate MockConsole in spock test and pass it to MyClass constructor.

**update-201312272156**

I played with spock a little bit. The problem with mocking "readLine(String fmt, Object ... args)" seems to be specific to varargs (or to last arg being a list, which is the same to groovy). I managed to reduce a problem to the following scenario:

Define an interface:

```
interface IConsole {
  String readLine(String fmt, Object ... args)
}
```

Define test:

```
class TestInputMethods extends Specification {

  def 'test console input'() {
    setup:
    def consoleMock = GroovyMock(IConsole)
    1 * consoleMock.readLine(_) >> 'validResponse'

    when:
    // here we get exception "wrong number of arguments":
    def testResult = consoleMock.readLine('testPrompt')

    then:
    testResult == 'validResponse'
  }
}
```

this variant of test fails with exception "wrong number of arguments". Particularly, spock thinks that readLine accepts 2 arguments and ignores the fact that second argument is vararg. Proof: if we remove "Object ... args" from IConsole.readLine, the test completes successfully.

**Here is Workaround** for this (hopefully temporary) problem: change the call to readLine to:

```
def testResult = consoleMock.readLine('testPrompt', [] as Object[])
```

then test completes successfully.

I also tried the same code against spock 1.0-groovy-2.0-SNAPSHOT - the problem is the same.

**update-201312280030**

The problem with varargs is solved! Many thanks to @charlesg, who answered my related question at: [Spock: mock a method with varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808189/spock-mock-a-method-with-varargs)

The solution is the following: replace GroovyMock with Mock, then varargs are properly interpreted.

Comment: Tried to follow this suggestion, but it still did not work.  Please see the edits to my question above.

Comment: @JoeG, I extended my answer with the research on this problem.

Comment: That confirms what I saw as well.  Unfortunately, that workaround won't work for me - I never call the mock directly the code under test calls what it believes to be a real object.  Like my putting null there, to make the test work requires changing the code under test as a workaround for this problem in the framework.

Comment: @JoeG, the problem with varargs is now solved :) See my latest update to the answer.