# Spock failing to intercept method with optional argument(s)

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I'm trying to update a groovy unit test and I'm having an issue with the following code:

```
def "getDatasetRecords() returns PaginatedSearchResults with a set of DatasetRecords from the repo"() {
    setup:
    def mockRecords = []
    def originalResults = Mock(PaginatedSearchResults)

    def modelMock = Mock(Model) {
        isEmpty() >> false
        filter(_ as org.matonto.rdf.api.Resource, _ as IRI, _ as Value, null) >>> it // Also tried (*_), (_, _, _) w&w/o Classes
    }

    def recordMock = Mock(DatasetRecord)
    recordMock.getModel() >> modelMock

    7.times { mockRecords <<  recordMock }
    originalResults.getPage() >> mockRecords
    originalResults.getPageNumber() >> 1
    originalResults.getTotalSize() >> 7
    originalResults.getPageSize() >> 10
    catalogManagerMock.findRecord(*_) >>> originalResults

    expect:
    def results = service.getDatasetRecords(new DatasetPaginatedSearchParams(vf))
    results.getPage().size() == 7
    results.getPageSize() == 10
    results.getTotalSize() == 7
    results.getPageNumber() == 1
}
```

When I debug the code: it appears that `model.filter` is returning `null` and a NPE is being thrown when `isEmpty()` is called here:

```
public Optional<DatasetRecord> getExisting(Resource resource, Model model, ValueFactory valueFactory, ValueConverterRegistry valueConverterRegistry) {
   return (model.filter(resource, valueFactory.createIRI(RDF_TYPE_IRI), this.getTypeIRI()).isEmpty()?Optional.empty():Optional.of(new DatasetRecordImpl(resource, model, valueFactory, valueConverterRegistry)));
}
```

The NPE:

```
getDatasetRecords() returns PaginatedSearchResults with a set of DatasetRecords from the repo(org.matonto.dataset.impl.SimpleDatasetManagerSpec)  Time elapsed: 0.028 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.matonto.dataset.ontology.dataset.DatasetRecordFactory.getExisting(DatasetRecordFactory.java:65)
    at org.matonto.rdf.orm.AbstractOrmFactory.getExisting(AbstractOrmFactory.java:159)
    at org.matonto.rdf.orm.AbstractOrmFactory.getExisting(AbstractOrmFactory.java:167)
    at org.matonto.dataset.pagination.DatasetRecordSearchResults.lambda$new$0(DatasetRecordSearchResults.java:46)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.matonto.dataset.pagination.DatasetRecordSearchResults.<init>(DatasetRecordSearchResults.java:47)
    at org.matonto.dataset.impl.SimpleDatasetManager.getDatasetRecords(SimpleDatasetManager.java:155)
    at org.matonto.dataset.impl.SimpleDatasetManagerSpec.getDatasetRecords() returns PaginatedSearchResults with a set of DatasetRecords from the repo(SimpleDatasetManagerSpec.groovy:371)
```

The definition for `filter`:

```
Model filter(Resource subject, IRI predicate, Value object, Resource... context);
```

I have tried fully specking the method signature for the mock object with and without the last parameter. Any help would be appreciated getting the mock interceptor for the `filter` method working here.

Comment: mocks should not be used with `expect`, please use `given-when-then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
class Spec extends Specification {
    def 'mock returns itself'() {
        given:
        def mock = Mock(Model) {
            filter(*_) >> it
        }

        expect:
        mock.filter(1, 2, 3, 4) == mock
        mock.filter(1, 2, 3) == mock
    }
}

class Model {
    Model filter(a, b, c, ... d) {
        new Model()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did not work for me. Also, `Model.filter(a, b, c, ...d)` (not entirely sure about the syntax in Groovy for the optional arguments at the end). I think it's the optional arguments at the end that's interfering with the method mock.

Comment: @NotNormal, if you change `GrooyMock` to `Mock` it should just work. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808189/spock-mock-a-method-with-varargs

Comment: I started out that way and have moved back this morning. When debugging through the code: I evaluate the expression `model.filter(resource, valueFactory.createIRI(RDF_TYPE_IRI), this.getTypeIRI())` and the expression evaluator in IntelliJ returns `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Invalid argument count: expected 4, received 3` which tells me the interceptor for the mock is failing to process it.

Comment: Ok, no idea then.

Answer (score 1):

My code (above) was fine, but a small change was made:

```
def modelMock = Mock(Model) {
    isEmpty() >> false
    filter(*_) >> it
}
```

My problem turned out to be IntelliJ and trying to debug it there.